# Convert value of string to name of init class

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var name_of_player = "Ted"
window[name_of_player] = new Player(name_of_player);

function show(player) {
    player.return_name;
```

I would like something like this:

```
show(name_of_player); --> Ted.return_name;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to get the object via `window[player]`? Please elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you want `window[name_of_player].return_name` inside the `show()` method in replace of `player.return_name`?. However, it is a little unclear what you need...

Comment: No, I created variable Ted with instance of class, so `var Ted = new Player("Ted");`. And now I want to send `string "Ted"` to `function show` which do `get return_name()` in class `Player`, so `Ted.return_name;`.

Comment: _No, I created variable Ted with instance of class, so `var Ted = new Player("Ted");`_. Then please, try to complete your code, so we don't have to assume or guess things about it.

Comment: @JohnDoe please add the definition of the `Player` class, or a minimal code that ilustrates it...

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same as you did when creating the player:

```
function show(player) {
    return window[player].return_name;
}
```

Or simply:

```
function show(player) {
    return player;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable inside the function from `window` object. In the `Player` constructor set the argument passed as `return_name` of instance.

```js
function Player(name){
  this.return_name = name;
}

var name_of_player = "Ted"
window[name_of_player] = new Player(name_of_player);

function show(player) {
    return window[player].return_name;
}

console.log(show(name_of_player))
```